# True and false in C in if statement with getopt()

Tags: c, unix, if-statement, argv, getopts

I have a hard time in understatanding how true and false works with "if statement" when I am using argv & getopt.

This is the simple code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int opt;

while ((opt = getopt (argc, argv, "i:l:")) != -1)
        switch (opt) {
        case 'i':
                printf("This is option i");           
                break;
        case 'l':
                printf("This is option l");
                break;
        default:
                fprintf(stderr,"Usage: %s here goes usage\n",argv[0]); 
    }

if (argc == 1) {
    printf("Without options");
}

if ((argc == 2) && (argv[1] != "-l") || (argv[1] != "-i")) {
    printf("Without option -l or -i but with other argument \n");
    printf("argv[1] is %s\n", argv[1]); 
}
```

Usage:

```
./a.out foo
```

Output:

```
Without option -l or -i but with other argument 
argv[1] is foo
```

It's good so far. Now let me check if it works when argv[1] is "-l":

Usage:

```
./a.out -l
```

Output:

```
./a.out: option requires an argument -- 'l'
Usage: ./a.out here goes usage
Without option -l or -i but with other argument 
argv[1] is -l
```

Getopt works fine, but second information occurs even if argv[1] is -l and I set in "if" statement that (argv[1] != "-l"). Why it works like that? I have no clue.

Thanks for any answer.
B.

Comment: use `strcmp` to compare strings, not `!=`. You will need `#include <string.h>`

Comment: Also , `a && b || c` means `(a && b) || c`, use parentheses if your intent is `a && (b || c)` as seems to be

Comment: As an aside, your problem actually has nothing to do with `getopt`. And I find thanking for *any* answer a little strange, what if the answer is "you need to format your hard disk without a backup"? Just kidding, don't do that :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Hi! Thanks for your "any" answer then :). Sorry, I'm not a native. Sometimes, I'm just copying frazes from my own language that are perfectly correct with their meaning and translate them directly into English, which may sound strange in English. Sorry for that. When it comes to getopt, I started to learn C just recently, I thought that maybe it is connected because in fact I wanted to use options from getopt in my "if statement".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do *not* use:

```
argv[1] != "-l"
```

to compare strings in C<sup>(a)</sup>, this compares the *addresses* of two arrays of `char`<sup>(b)</sup> rather than the *contents* of those two strings. Instaed, you should be using:

```
strcmp(argv[1], "-l") == 0
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> This is one of the things fixed in C++ strings, the equality operators there compare the content of the strings.

<sup>(b)</sup> This may *sometimes* seem to work with something like `"xyzzy" == "xyzzy"` but that's only because the compiler is allowed (but not required) to fold identical string constants together (so they take less room). It generally is not possible when one of the strings is not a constant (such as when it's passed on the command line).

Answer (score 2):

You re comparing two `char *`s using `!=` this compares the addresses.

```
(argv[1] != "-l")
```

The way to compare strings is using `strcmp`. Mind hat the `strcmp` function is "trinary", and returns either a negative or positive value if the strings are different (to provide order) or `0` if equal.

`(strcmp(argv[1], "-l") == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

AND (`&&`) has precedence over OR (`||`), so I think your code inside the `if` statement is interpreted like this:
 `if (((argc == 2) && (argv[1] != "-l")) || (argv[1] != "-i"))`
 So the logic inside of it is always true, because even if your option IS `-l` and it's one and only (number of option != 2) it's also true that the option you typed is NOT `-i`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but it didn't work also for "&&" only inside the statement. I tried it :). Thanks for your reply and time!

Comment: you're welcome, anyway paxdiablo clearly fixed it (;